# How to access the functionality in two different modules?

Tags: 6, hooks

Hai I have modules called `sites/all/module/dashboard` and `sites/all/module/userpoints`

I need to display userpoints in inside the dashboard. There is a hook in `sites/all/module/userpoints/userpoints.module` called userpoints_block() to display the userpoints . Can i access this hook `userpoints_block()` in `sites/all/module/dashboard/dashboard.module` . How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [module_invoke()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7) to call the functions in other module

Comment: Could you please tell me that where i have to put this module_invoke

Comment: Thanks sathish. Its worked for me after i put this code `$block = module_invoke('userpoints', 'block', 'view',1);
print $block['content'];`

Answer (score 1):

[module_invoke](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/6) seems to be a very handy option for this

(ex)
To get content of the Most Recent Poll (core module's block) content

```
module_invoke('poll', 'block', 'view', '0');
```

The first argument is the name of the module, second being hook, third and fourth are the params for the hook namely condition ('view') and block delta value (0). The return value is  an array of block subject and content.